# Meaning of "fresher than fresh"

Tags: american-english

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Usage and correctness of the term “Better than Best”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67680/usage-and-correctness-of-the-term-better-than-best)

> The **fresher than fresh** slogans of our relentless advertising

What does *fresher than fresh* mean? Does it mean more and more fresh?

Answer (score 6):

There's a reasonably common pattern to say:

> (some adjective)er than (the same adjective)

Fresher than fresh.
Faster than fast.
Smarter than smart.
etc.

It's just meant to be a clever way to make a superlative out of the adjective.   It's not just fresh, or fresher, or super-fresh, it's *fresher than fresh*.

In your example, it would most likely mean that the slogans were extremely fresh — or new to the ad market.